# Can someone explain this C++ code to me which is part of LinkedList program?

Tags: c++

I know this question won't be specific but I can't figure out what this code is doing:

I have a constructor for a class:
`ListNode(const T & data) : data(data), next(nullptr) {}` that initializes next as a nullptr.

Then I have this code:

```
template <typename T>
const T & List<T>::operator[](unsigned index) {
  ListNode *thru = head_;

  while (index > 0 && thru->next != nullptr) {
    thru = thru->next;
    index--;
  }  

  return thru->data;
}
```

Is this trying to define `[]` as an operator that will return the 'data' at the given 'index'? And what is `thru = thru->next;` trying to accomplish? Can someone help? Also what why `index--` is being done in the context of this code?

Comment: `thru = thru->next;` is setting the pointer to the next element in the list. It's how you generally traverse a linked list

Comment: This function is iterating through the linked list (the while loop) and returns data at the index/node # of the linked list that was passed to it.

Comment: How does it know when it's reached the 'index' that we've specified?

Comment: Via the combination of `index > 0` and `index--` - `index` will become 0 when it iterated often enough

Comment: @UnholySheep Ohh wow, got it. Isn't there a better way to create this loop?

Comment: @MHA: A fore loop might be more typical but there's nothing particularly unreasonable about this (other than an index-based operator[] being a somewhat odd operation for a list to support).

Comment: Note: Returning the last item if a non-existent item is requested is a future bug factory. Careful with that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this trying to define [] as an operator that will return the 'data' at the given 'index'?

Yes. Basically it means you can do this:

```
List<int> l; //suppose it has values
int x = l[3]; //access the third element.
```

> And what is thru = thru->next; trying to accomplish?

It is trying to find the `index` position provided in the argument. You see, lists can't be accessed directly with indexes. Let me explain with values:

```
suppose index = 3

 // loop keeps running till index is not 0
  while (index > 0 && thru->next != nullptr) {
    thru = thru->next;     //move forward in list, "next" is the next item in list
    index--;               //decrease index by 1 on every iteration
  }
```

If the index is 3, it will be decremented 3 times, and `thru` will move *forward* in list by 3 items. In other words, we move forward in list till index is not 0. When index has reached 0, `thru` contains the value at position `index` and that value is returned from the function.